# UWP Hub need vertical scrolling

Tags: c#, uwp

for testing purposes I have a Hub control in UWP that looks like this:

```
            <Hub x:Name="hubTest1">
                <HubSection Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="200" Background="CadetBlue" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Header="#" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <HubSection.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Foreground="White">This is some Test</TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </HubSection.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                            <RichTextBlock Height="1000" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <Paragraph>
                                    This is a test.
                                    <LineBreak></LineBreak>
                                    This is a test.
                                    <LineBreak></LineBreak>
                                    This is a test.
                                    <LineBreak></LineBreak>
                                    ... Repeated many times ...
                                </Paragraph>
                            </RichTextBlock>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </HubSection>
                <HubSection Margin="10,0,0,0" Background="BlueViolet" Width="300" Foreground="White" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Header="#">
                    <HubSection.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Foreground="White">This is some Test</TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </HubSection.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock>This is a test 2</TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </HubSection>
            </Hub>
```

Where I'm having trouble is I want the first HubSection to be scrollable off the page vertically when filled with more content than the screen. It only goes to the edge though. The inside ScrollViewer does scroll the text down vertically, but it's inside the inner container of the DataTemplate and isn't giving the necessary result. Also the Hub is inside a SplitView.Content container, I'm not sure if that affects the behavior of the Hub or not. I'm wondering if it's possible to get the desired behavior? Any help you guys can give is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inside `ScrollViewer` doesn't go all the way down because you gave the `RichTextBlock` a fixed `Height` of `1000px`. Remove it and the problem should go away.

Also it's OK to put the `Hub` inside a `SplitView` and have vertically scrolling content too.

### Update

If you want the whole `HubSection` including the header to be scrollable, two things you need to do:

1. Remove the `ScrollViewer` inside your `DataTemplate`.
2. Create a new `Style` for your `HubSection` and inside its
   `ControlTemplate`, insert a new `ScrollViewer` as its top level
   container. Something like this -

---

```
<Style x:Key="HubSectionStyle1"
        TargetType="HubSection">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
            Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
            Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
            Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
            Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="Padding"
            Value="12,10,12,0" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop"
            Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals"
            Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="HubSection">
                <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Border.Resources>
                            <ControlTemplate x:Key="HeaderButtonTemplate"
                                                TargetType="Button">
                                <Grid x:Name="ButtonRoot"
                                        Background="Transparent">
                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonRoot" />
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                                Value="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonRoot" />
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                                Value="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonRoot" />
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                                Value="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="ImitatedTextBlock">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                                Value="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderForeground}" />
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                        OpticalMarginAlignment="TrimSideBearings"
                                                        VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Border.Resources>
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="HubHeaderPlaceholder"
                                        Grid.Row="0" />
                            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Button x:Name="HeaderButton"
                                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                        Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                        Foreground="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderButtonForeground}"
                                        FontWeight="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderThemeFontWeight}"
                                        FontSize="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderThemeFontSize}"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                        IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                        IsTabStop="False"
                                        Margin="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderThemeMargin}"
                                        Grid.Row="1"
                                        Template="{StaticResource HeaderButtonTemplate}"
                                        UseSystemFocusVisuals="True"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                <Button x:Name="SeeMoreButton"
                                        Grid.Column="1"
                                        Foreground="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderButtonForeground}"
                                        FontWeight="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderThemeFontWeight}"
                                        FontSize="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderSeeMoreThemeFontSize}"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                        Margin="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderSeeMoreThemeMargin}"
                                        Grid.Row="1"
                                        Template="{StaticResource HeaderButtonTemplate}"
                                        UseSystemFocusVisuals="True"
                                        Visibility="Collapsed"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                            </Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                Grid.Row="2"
                                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks Justin, it looks like it still doesn't do what I'm wanting to do though. Here's a screenshot, I'm running at 1920x1080 with 175% scaling: http://imgur.com/a/FyfbU Is there a way to get the whole HubSection to scroll? That scrollbar gets in the way of the text as it's scrolling. I can change the right Margin to -10 or so and that sort of fixes it, but I'm not sure how that might look in other resolutions or orientations or if that's bad design to use a Margin in this case.

Comment: Here's the link, I was having trouble with my internet connection: https://1drv.ms/i/s!AmWCgKo76PeMrRDhuXZkdzxx7Uq3

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the _whole_ `HubSection` including the big "This is some Test" heading to scroll? 'cause looking at the screenshot the content seems to be already scrollable?

Comment: Yes if that's possible I would like for the whole content area of the HubSection to be vertically scrollable including the header. If I have some large area of content like a readable article I'd like it all to be scrollable inside that container.

Comment: Glad it helped. :)